# Chrome extension's contentScript won't get querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, google-chrome-extension

I have problems getting results from document.querySelectorAll

The following code is working perfect inside browser's debugging console:

```
document.querySelectorAll("td.answer-text > div").forEach(function(el, i, arr)
    {
        var a = el.innerHTML;
        a = a.replaceAll('<div>', '');
        a = a.replaceAll('</div>', '');
        a = a.replaceAll('<br>', '');
        a = a.replaceAll('&nbsp;', ' ');
        console.log(a);
    });
```

Inside of contentScript.js I get empty array result: Array(0)

```
window.addEventListener ("load", function()
{
    document.querySelectorAll("td.answer-text > div").forEach(function(el, i, arr)
    {
        var a = el.innerHTML;
        a = a.replaceAll('<div>', '');
        a = a.replaceAll('</div>', '');
        a = a.replaceAll('<br>', '');
        a = a.replaceAll('&nbsp;', ' ');
        console.log(a);
    });
}, false);
```

manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
...
 "content_scripts": [{
  "all_frames": true,
  "js": ["content.js"],
  "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
  "run_at": "document_end"
}],
"background": {
 ...
],
"persistent": false
},
"options_page": "options.html",
"permissions": [ "activeTab", "storage", "tabs", "webNavigation",  " 
 <all_urls>" ]
```

}

Any suggestions?

Comment: These elements are generated dynamically after `load` event. Use MutationObserver or setInterval to detect them.

Comment: ok, i'll give a try!

Comment: added the following code: 

var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations)
{
 mutations.forEach(function(mutation)
 {
  console.log(mutation);
    });
});

but there no more changes on DOM after load (((

Comment: @MrMan you need to [observe it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe)

Comment: @appleapple now it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items may be generated after `load` event, you can use `MutationObserver` to wait for it to be inserted.

```js
// target element is delay loaded
window.addEventListener ("load", function something_is_delay_loaded()
{
   setTimeout(()=>document
     .getElementById('parent')
     .insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div id=target>delay loaded item</div>')
   , 1000)
})

//so you would not found it on load
window.addEventListener ("load", function you_would_not_found_it_on_load()
{
  console.log('onload:', document.getElementById('target'))
})

window.addEventListener ("load", function()
{
   let mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(
      mutations=>mutations.forEach(x=>console.log('nodes add:', [...x.addedNodes]))
   )
   mutationObserver.observe(document.getElementById('parent'),{childList:true})
})
```

```html
<div id=parent></div>
```

Comment: I ommited load Event, but the answer is brilliant!

Comment: @MrMan true that you do not need onload because you use `document_end`:)